# present simple expresses future

Tags: tense, present-tense, clauses, future-tense, subordinate-clauses

I know  we can say:

**The plane takes off at 6:40 p.m.(expressing future)**

But can I say:

**The plane takes off at 6:40 p.m. when everything is ready.**

Or I should put "will" here

**The plane will take off at 6:40p.m. when everything is ready.**

Thanks so much!

Comment: Or *"The plane takes off at 6:40 pm, when everything will be ready."* Or maybe *"The plane takes off at 6:40 pm, if everything is ready."* Depending on what you want it to mean.